# DataGrid Not Binding Correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have one page with a `Tabcontrol` that contains two `DataGrids`. I am able to bind the first one without a hitch however the second will not receive any data no mattter what I try. I feel like it may be due to something to do with the `DataContext`, however I am still unsure.

This is how I bind my first `DataGrid`;

```
    private async void FillDataGrid()
    {
        var Companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>();
        var waitWindow = new PleaseWait();

        waitWindow.Show();
        Companies = await ReturnCompanies();
        CompanyICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Companies);
        DataContext = this;

        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
        waitWindow.Close();
    }
```

The `DataGrid` itself looks like this;

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="true" 
                      Margin="10" FontSize="14" 
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyICollectionView}"
                      MinColumnWidth="0">                       
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Town" Binding="{Binding Town}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Post Code" Binding="{Binding Postcode}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

My second `DataGrid` is bound in a very similar way;

```
    private async void FillContactsDataGrid(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var Contacts = new ObservableCollection<ContactsModel>();
        var waitWindow = new PleaseWait();

        waitWindow.Show();
        Contacts = await ReturnContacts();
        ContactsICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contacts);
        DataContext = this;

        contactsDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
        waitWindow.Close();
    }
```

The second `DataGrid`;

```
<DataGrid x:Name="contactsDataGrid" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="true" 
                      Margin="10" FontSize="14" 
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsICollectionView}"
                      MinColumnWidth="0"
                      Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding ContactDate, StringFormat=\{dd-MM-yyyy\}}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="To Person" Binding="{Binding PersonName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contract" Binding="{Binding Contract}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding TypeOfContact}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Made By" Binding="{Binding ContactMadeBy}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contract Summary" Binding="{Binding ContactDescription}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I have looped through the `ContactsICollectionView` and printed out details of the contacts and had no issue, so I know that the collections are being filled correctly, it's just the binding of the `DataGrids` where I'm going wrong.

Comment: use https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ and check the Binding and DataContext at runtime

Answer (score 1):

In your First DataGrid you are binding the Collection from a method.
        `private async void FillDataGrid()`

But for your second Grid, i guess it is from an event (Considering the arguments for the second event you posted.).
        `private async void FillContactsDataGrid(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)`

This is an event handler right?

There might be a problem because the 'this' in your second method(which is an event handler) points to the object which raised that event and not the window object as like in the first method.

Sorry i didn't make it as a comment. I don't have enough reputation yet to do that.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
Without seeing the entire code i can't find the real problem. The following might be little helpful
@ProgrammingDude is correct. `this` refers to the class it belongs to.

```
DataContext = this;
```

The above line binds your class (which `this` points to) with the `DataContext`. This makes the DataGrid binds with the members of the `this` class
1.  Make sure the event handler `FillContactsDataGrid` is inside the class which `this` points to
2. Make sure the object `ContactsICollectionView` is a member of the class which `this` points to
3. Is `ContactsICollectionView` a property?

Comment: You're quite right it is being done on a TabItem click. What would you suggest changing this to?

Comment: this should still refer to the instance of the class I believe, even if you are in an event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx